# How to use functions in vue lifecycle hooks?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have data that i need to get (and modify) from getters and pass it to two lifecycle hooks. How to do it without code duplication.

### Here is simplified example:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      someData: undefined,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['someGetter','otherGetter']),
  },
  mounted() {
    this.someData = this.someGetter + this.otherGetter; // how can i put this into function
  },
  beforeUpdate() {
    this.someData = this.someGetter + this.otherGetter; // and use it in this lifecycle hook instead of duplicating code
  },
};
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to not use a computed property to combine the two values?

Comment: Can I combine two computed properties in the other computed property? Edit: yes, i can — https://forum.vuejs.org/t/getters-into-a-computed-method/5149/4.

Comment: @brachkoff of course!